# wireless authentication window pops up even after disabling it in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, gnome, network-manager

I have tried applying the following settings to suppress this pop-up on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but the window still pops-up randomly. Is this is a bug in the OS or am I missing something else?

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet suppress-wireless-networks-available true
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-disconnected-notifications true
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-vpn-notifications true
gsettings set org.gnome.nm-applet disable-connected-notifications true
```

Comment: The wireless authentication popup says, roughly, that your wireless is now disconnected and the password that is required to reconnect must be supplied by you because it is either not stored in the system or it is no longer valid and, further, you won't be reconnected until the password is supplied. Why would you want to suppress and ignore that message?

Comment: I want to ignore that message because the wireless pop-up is populated with the password already which is stored properly and is valid. The pop-up is useless to my needs as it would automatically connect to internet whenever it can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the pop-up is caused by the nm-applet program so the solution which worked for me is renaming the nm-applet from /usr/bin/nm-applet to /usr/bin/NM-APPLET.